# I can't change regional options

Tags: regional-settings, windows-xp-embedded

I have a mini pc that came with a pre-installed windows xp embedded. Problem is that I want to change a regional settings( so I can have a 24h datetime and so on...) but everytime I change it to what I want I am getting a box that I need to accept so it can restarts. 
When PC restarts regional setting are the same.

How to make this to save settings as permanent ?

Comment: Does the mini PC have a hard disk with Windows installed on it or is the OS installed in ROM?

Comment: It has a ssd drive which has windows installed. Do I need to install new version of win xp to make this work? Or there is some workaround solution?

Comment: Sounds like the SSD is getting a fresh copy of the OS from somewhere every time you restart.

Comment: It was resetting everything at the beginning then I started one script which turn off system settings now I can use it normally except that regional settings are always restarting

Comment: A workaround might be to identify the registry settings you're changing using the Regional and Language Options and export them in regedit to a .reg file. Afterwards you can create a batch file that merges those setting back in and have the script executed at startup by putting it in the Startup folder.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what you are running into is XP Embedded's [Enhanced Write Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912906%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) (EWF)

> Enhanced Write Filter (EWF) provides the ability to write-protect a run-time image. By redirecting all write requests to either a separate disk partition or RAM, EWF allows the run-time image to maintain the appearance of a writeable run-time image. Additionally, Enhanced Write Filter provides the ability to deploy a run-time image onto read-only media, such as a CD-ROM.

You can turn it off using the EWF Manager Application (if it was included in the Embedded image).

To start the EWF Manager run `Ewfmgr`, and use it to get status, enable and/or disable the EWF, etc.

More info from MS here: [Using the Enhanced Write Filter (EWF) in Windows XP Embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838511%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)

Comment: This PC is actually preinstalled as a thin client so I have started a .bat file which says "Turn off system protect". Is that what I needed to do? Where do I find that `Ewfmgr`

Comment: Yeah most likely that batch file will run it for you.  Why not open the batch file in Notepad and look at it? :)   Usually you unlock, reboot, make changes, lock it, and reboot again.  Have you tried just running Ewfmgr from a command prompt or the "Run" dialog?

Comment: this is what is inside the file `EWFMGR C: -COMMITANDDISABLE
shutdown -r -f -t 01` but it has an error when executing. I think it can't find ewfmgr

Comment: Well since I can't see the error from here, what was it? :)  Again, Have you tried just running Ewfmgr from a command prompt or the "Run" dialog?  You should really hit up the links I put in my answer, as XP Embedded is not the same as a usual XP install you need to do some studying. ;)